# Condición if o CASE WHEN sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta

```
SELECT SI_Num_Inventario = COALESCE(t.SI_Num_Inventario, c.SI_Num_Inventario)
    ,SI_Ubicacion = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion, c.SI_Ubicacion)
    ,SI_Ubicacion_Fisica = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica, c.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica)
    ,SI_Num_Articulo = COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo)
    ,NULL
    ,SI_Num_Conteo = COALESCE(cs.SI_Num_Conteo, 2)
    ,GETDATE()
    ,'Admin'
    ,c.SI_OV
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t
FULL JOIN SI_Conteo c ON t.SI_Articulo = c.SI_Num_Articulo
    AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c.SI_Ubicacion
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m ON t.SI_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo
    OR c.SI_Num_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo
FULL JOIN SI_Consecutivo cs ON c.SI_Num_Inventario = cs.SI_Num_Inventario
    AND cs.SI_Estado = 0
WHERE c.SI_Num_Articulo = 201423
    OR t.SI_Articulo = 201423
```

Y estoy tratando de decirle que si `c.SI_OV IS NULL` me haga este `INSERT`:

```
IF c.SI_OV IS NULL
    INSERT INTO SI_Conteo(SI_Num_Inventario, SI_Ubicacion,SI_Num_Articulo,SI_Cantidad,SI_Num_Conteo,SI_Fecha_Conteo, SI_Usuario,SI_OV)
```

Y si no es `NULL` me inserte este otro:

```
ELSE
    INSERT INTO SI_Conteo(SI_Num_Inventario, SI_Ubicacion_Fisica,SI_Num_Articulo,SI_Cantidad,SI_Num_Conteo,SI_Fecha_Conteo,SI_Usuario,SI_OV)
END IF;
```

O realizarlo con un `CASE WHEN`:

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr lo que deseas, requieres apoyarte de una tabla temporal con la misma definición de los campos que requieres seleccionar (a modo de ejemplo puse como tipo de dato `INT` a algunos campos de la tabla temporal).

Luego, el resultado de la consulta lo vas a insertar en la tabla temporal para que después puedas validar el resultado de `SI_OV` y evaluar qué tipo de `INSERT` se realizará.

El código qudaría de la siguiente manera:

```
DECLARE @resultado TABLE (
     SI_Num_Inventario INT
    ,SI_Ubicacion INT
    ,SI_Ubicacion_Fisica INT
    ,SI_Num_Articulo INT
    ,DatoNulo INT
    ,SI_Num_Conteo INT
    ,Fecha DATETIME
    ,Usuario VARCHAR(32)
    ,SI_OV INT
)

INSERT INTO @resultado
SELECT SI_Num_Inventario = COALESCE(t.SI_Num_Inventario, c.SI_Num_Inventario)
    ,SI_Ubicacion = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion, c.SI_Ubicacion)
    ,SI_Ubicacion_Fisica = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica, c.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica)
    ,SI_Num_Articulo = COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo)
    ,NULL
    ,SI_Num_Conteo = COALESCE(cs.SI_Num_Conteo, 2)
    ,GETDATE()
    ,'Admin'
    ,c.SI_OV
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t
FULL JOIN SI_Conteo c ON t.SI_Articulo = c.SI_Num_Articulo
    AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c.SI_Ubicacion
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m ON t.SI_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo
    OR c.SI_Num_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo
FULL JOIN SI_Consecutivo cs ON c.SI_Num_Inventario = cs.SI_Num_Inventario
    AND cs.SI_Estado = 0
WHERE c.SI_Num_Articulo = 201423
    OR t.SI_Articulo = 201423

IF (SELECT TOP 1 SI_OV FROM @resultado) IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SI_Conteo(SI_Num_Inventario, SI_Ubicacion,SI_Num_Articulo,SI_Cantidad,SI_Num_Conteo,SI_Fecha_Conteo, SI_Usuario,SI_OV)
    SELECT SI_Num_Inventario, SI_Ubicacion,SI_Num_Articulo,SI_Cantidad,SI_Num_Conteo,SI_Fecha_Conteo, SI_Usuario,SI_OV
    FROM @resultado
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SI_Conteo(SI_Num_Inventario, SI_Ubicacion_Fisica,SI_Num_Articulo,SI_Cantidad,SI_Num_Conteo,SI_Fecha_Conteo,SI_Usuario,SI_OV)
    SELECT SI_Num_Inventario, SI_Ubicacion_Fisica,SI_Num_Articulo,SI_Cantidad,SI_Num_Conteo,SI_Fecha_Conteo,SI_Usuario,SI_OV
    FROM @resultado
END
```

Nota: el resultado de los `INSERT` está suponiendo que la consulta principal siempre regresará un resultado, ya que si no llegara a traer resultados o más de un resultado, el comportamiento talvés no es el que tú esperas.